# SQL weighted average

Tags: sql, postgresql

Have a table like below.

```
make   | model | engine | cars_checked | avg_mileage
---------------------------------------|--------
suzuki | sx4   | petrol | 11           | 12
suzuki | sx4   | diesel | 150          | 16
suzuki | swift | petrol | 140          | 15
suzuki | swift | diesel | 18           | 19
toyota | prius | petrol | 16           | 17
toyota | prius | hybrid | 250          | 24
```

The output desired is

1. average mileage by engine (petrol, diesel)
2. average mileage by make
3. average mileage by model

Cannot do a simple `group by` as the weight-age in terms of the number of samples for each record (`cars_checked`) need to considered so as to avoid the average of averages problem.

What is the right way to achieve it ? is there a way to consider the number of samples to do a weighted average in `group by` ?

**update** - output format added for #1 above as example

```
engine   | mileage_by_engine
--------------------------
petrol   | xx.z
diesel   | yy.z
```

Comment: can you show how the output should look like?

Comment: @vkp - updated with output format

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
SELECT engine, SUM(cars_checked * avg_mileage) / SUM(cars_checked) AS avgMilageByEngine
FROM [YOUR_TABLE]
GROUP BY engine

SELECT make, SUM(cars_checked * avg_mileage) / SUM(cars_checked) AS avgMilageByMake
FROM [YOUR_TABLE]
GROUP BY make

SELECT model, SUM(cars_checked * avg_mileage) / SUM(cars_checked) AS avgMilageByModel
FROM [YOUR_TABLE]
GROUP BY model
```

Answer (score 6):

There's a better way.  Create an aggregate function.  Here's how you do it.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.numeric_weighted_average_accum(
    "Previous" numeric[],
    "ThisDatum" numeric,
    "ThisWeight" numeric)
    RETURNS numeric[]
    LANGUAGE 'sql'
    COST 100
    VOLATILE STRICT PARALLEL UNSAFE
AS $BODY$
 SELECT ARRAY["Previous"[1] + ("ThisDatum" * "ThisWeight"), "Previous"[2] + "ThisWeight"];
$BODY$;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION numeric_weighted_average_final(
    "NWA" numeric[])
    RETURNS numeric
    LANGUAGE 'sql'
    COST 100
    VOLATILE STRICT PARALLEL UNSAFE
AS $BODY$
SELECT "NWA"[1] / "NWA"[2];
$BODY$;

CREATE OR REPLACE AGGREGATE weighted_average(datum numeric, weight numeric) (
    SFUNC = numeric_weighted_average_accum,
    STYPE = numeric[] ,
    FINALFUNC = numeric_weighted_average_final,
    FINALFUNC_MODIFY = READ_ONLY,
    INITCOND = '{0,0}',
    MFINALFUNC_MODIFY = READ_ONLY
);
```

Then, you can do

```
SELECT name, weighted_average(avgcolumn, weightcolumn) AS "WeightedAverage" GROUP BY name;
```

I'm sure there's room here for efficiency improvements, and would be happy to hear about them.

HTH,

Comment: why are these functions `VOLATILE` and `PARALLEL UNSAFE`? I would have guessed they'd be `IMMUTABLE PARALLEL SAFE`.

Answer (score 5):

One way to simplify the query is to use `grouping sets`:

```
select engine, make, model,
       sum(cars_check * avg_mileage) / sum(cars_checked) as avgMilage
from t
group by grouping sets ((engine), (make), (model));
```

The output format has non-NULL values only in the column *not* being aggregated.